# How can I disable visual effects in Lion?

Tags: macos, gpu, temperature

I've just installed Lion on my 24" iMac from 2006 and do have again problems with screen-freezes due to overheating. This is a known issue with the 2006 iMacs since OSX late 10.5 / 10.6. While for (Snow) Leopard it was possible to overcome this problem by deactivating a kernel extension of the graphics card driver, this does not seem to have any effect with Lion.

How do i disable visual effects with Lion, such as smooth window-moving, drop-shadows everywhere, window-animations, smooth video playback etc.?

Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

I just wanted to make clear, that I have already tried some UI tweak applications like [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail) and iTweax. While they are able to disable some animations, the most "expensive" effects are not turned off (at least not as far as I know) like smooth window moving and drop-shadows.

Answer (score 2):

The place to go to disable animation is in the [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) preference pane. You can disable a lot of the animations. Has a few Lion preferences and is updated in realtime from the community.

Comment: thanks a lot! i will have a look and try if this solves my problems. if so, i will get back and accept this as answer!

Comment: it's pretty unfortunate that Apple didn't build a native control panel or toggle for the animations

Answer (score 1):

### [TinkerTool 4.7 (free version)](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)

has many customization options. New features include:

> Release 4.7 (Build 110906)
>
> - disable the animation effect when opening windows 
>     (Lion only).
> - disable the animation effect when opening a
>     reply window in Apple Mail (Lion only).